# Not loading JS File for the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

When I load my page for the first time its not showing the global functions.

example:

```
function abc() {
   alert("not working 1st time");
}
```

if we refresh the page again then its working perfectly.There is not error in the console also.

If we open the developer tool and refresh the page then all the global methods are working fine.

If we refresh the page with out developer tool then its showing error

How can I fix this one.

Even the page in console is showing blank.

Global function means those are not inside document ready. all the document ready methods are working fine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where in the document are the functions?

Comment: I have written some function in document and some are in  external js file. Both are not working

Comment: If I tried to call the method from console then its showing function is undefined

Comment: @bhagirathi as far I know, functions those are included on page load, or you can say that In docuemnt.ready those are called at the time of loading .

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        abc();
        function abc() {
            
            alert("not working 1st time");
            
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it will work but in my application its not working don't know why?

Comment: If we will open the developer tool and check then its working perfectly. Weird I know but don't know what to try and where to find the issue

Comment: copy all my code and paste in your application, try it.if my post help you , mark it please!

Comment: its not working, this is my question that this code is not working in my application.

Comment: Is it possible that you make the call before the actual definition? order is important